# Java Cucumber - Trivago Cluecumber not creating report via runnable jar

Tags: java, maven, cucumber, pom.xml, bdd

I have a Java Cucumber project which I have to run via an executable jar (`java -jar`) instead of maven (`mvn`).
I am trying to add the Trivago Cluecumber report plugin (https://github.com/trivago/cluecumber-report-plugin) into it but it only works when I call it via the maven command:

`mvn cluecumber-report:reporting`

When I run the project via `java -jar` I can see that the plugin creates the `.json` file but does not create the reports with the html,css,js page.

Is there a way I can fire this plugin from my java code instead of the maven plugin in the `pom.xml`?

Or is there a way I can hook this plugin execution after the java cucumber framework runs?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As Cluecumber in its current form is a Maven project, it needs to be invoked via Maven. Future versions of Cluecumber may also be usable without Maven.